# Choosing the appropriate operators for sequential fetches

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am using RxJS event streams along with the fetch API to make two sequential HTTP requests, where results of the first request must be passed along to the second. I am pretty close here however, combining the two streams is being problematic:

```
const xhrUrlBase = "http://localhost:4556/api";
const xhrButton = document.querySelector("#xhr-rxjs");
const xhrTriggerClickStream = fromEvent(xhrButton, "click");
const xhr$ = of(xhrUrlBase).pipe(
  concatMap(url => {
    return fromFetch(`${xhrUrlBase}/a`).pipe(
      switchMap(response => response.json())
    );
  }),
  concatMap(fromFirstCall => {
    return fromFetch(`${xhrUrlBase}/b?fromA=${fromFirstCall.toB}`).pipe(
      switchMap(response => response.json()),
      map(fromSecondCall => ({
        fromFirstCall,
        fromSecondCall
      }))
    );
  })
);

/* option A */
const clickAndXhr$ = xhrTriggerClickStream
   .pipe(
     flatMap(() => xhr$)
   )

/* option B */
const clickAndXhr$ = combineLatest(
    xhrTriggerClickStream,
    xhr$
)

clickAndXhr$.subscribe(([, returnedDataFromBothHttpRequests]) => {
  console.log({ returnedDataFromBothHttpRequests }); // got data from both responses
});
```

Option [A] works, but makes the request each time I click the button (I'm still not fully sure I'm using the `flatMap` correctly here). I would like the functionality of `combineLatest` where I take the latest streams from both like in Option [B]. However that options will not wait for a click, and the HTTP request is made on page load. Somewhere between the two is what I need.

A couple of questions arise from this exercise:

1) How to combine these streams so that the HTTP request is made once on button click, and thereafter, only the initial response is returned on subsequent button clicks?

2) The set up code (lines 4 - 20) is quite verbose and nested. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this. Where I have `switchMap` above, `flatMap` also will work (returns a value), whereas `map`, will get me (in the final subscription) a resolved promise. The console shows `[[PromsieStatus]]: "resolved"` and `[[PromiseValue]]: /* the correct object */`, however I don't really see how something like an rxjs switchMap has the ability to unwrap a promise. Why do both these operators work in this way?

3) Changing `concatMap` to `flatMap` also does not change the functionality. How can I know which is the appropriate operator when there appears to be so much overlap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `a` and add the `shareReplay` operator at the end of the `xhr$` stream.

```
const xhr$ = of(xhrUrlBase).pipe(
  concatMap(url => {
    return fromFetch(`${xhrUrlBase}/a`).pipe(
      switchMap(response => response.json())
    );
  }),
  concatMap(fromFirstCall => {
    return fromFetch(`${xhrUrlBase}/b?fromA=${fromFirstCall.toB}`).pipe(
      switchMap(response => response.json()),
      map(fromSecondCall => ({
        fromFirstCall,
        fromSecondCall
      }))
    );
  })
  shareReplay(1),
);
```

Comment: I see, thanks for this! Have you got any thoughts as to points 2-3?

Comment: Please refer to oles' answer for this, could not say it better.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding **first question**, as **@MoxxiManagram** already answered, [`shareReplay` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) can store previous result, so you don't have to make request again. But I would recommend to use config parameter instead of a single number. Since default behavior was changed previously and this might be confusing.

To answer your **second question**, your code is quite good. A bit shorter can be written like so:

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs; 
const { fromFetch } = rxjs.fetch;
const { shareReplay, mergeMap, map, tap } = rxjs.operators;

const r$ = fromFetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/1/").pipe(
  mergeMap(r => r.json()),
  mergeMap(person => fromFetch(person.homeworld).pipe(
    mergeMap(r => r.json()),
    map(planet => ({ person, planet }))
  )),

  // `bufferSize: 1` means remember only 1 last result
  // `refCount: flase` tell to not remove data when there is 0 subscribers
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false })
)

const button = document.getElementById("make-request");
const click$ = fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("sending request...")),
  mergeMap(() => r$)
)

click$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="make-request" type="button">Click me to print data</button>
```

And **third question** regarding `flatMap/mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`, `exhaustMap` and when to use them, take a look at awesome article [RxJS: Avoiding switchMap-Related Bugs](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) by Nicholas Jamieson. He have explained this in details